# jQuery to select element that contains xyz

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to apply CSS to the parent element that has a class that contains `xyz`,

The jQuery to select a class named `xyz` and to apply css is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".xyz").parent().css({"background-color": "yellow"});
});
```

But i'd like this to apply to an element that has a class of wxyz, which contains `xyz` e.g.

```
<select class="wxyz"">
<option>Sample</option>
</select>
```

The above is just an example, i could obviously also specify wxyz in a query function.

The reason why I need this functionality is because i've got a php script that produces 150 select boxes and each elements name is unique and  used to identify details about a booking. So the name includes o[1|0]fs[1|0]fe[1|0]..... and i'd like to apply different css if name contains f1, fs1, fe1

Comment: Instead of applying the css to elements that have a class named xyz, i'd like to apply to any element that has xyz in the class name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$("[class*=xyz]")` to match any particular string in a class. You can also check the documentation for the same. [Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp)

for now, try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("[class*=xyz]").parent().css({"background-color": "yellow"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this in jQuery you could use the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('select[class*="xyz"]').css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/0q7ry88o/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) like following.

```js
$("[class*=xyz]").parent().css({"background-color": "yellow"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select class="wxyz">
        <option>Sample</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
$("[class]").filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("class").indexOf("xyz")
}).css({ "background-color": "yellow"});
```